# awhy is allowed double quote inside input

Tags: php

I have problem with single or double quotes. I was read here some benefits of using single and double quotes, and i know different. My problem is next. Why can i use double quotes inside text input and it is echo success.

This is my form.

```
echo "<form action=\"display.php\" method=\"POST\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"text\">";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"display\">";
```

My display.php

```
 $word = $_POST['text'];
 echo $word;
```

My question is. Why is double quotes allowed in input? In my head,i think that if double quote come inside text input then we have 3 duoble quote and parser will not know where is end of string? i know what is escaping for database, but i ask for this case. Thanx

Comment: use one quote in double quote for example `"<input type='text' name='nest'>"`

Comment: the `\\ ` before the `"` 'escapes' that double quote, so the parser knows he should not interpret it as end of string.

Comment: Yes, it will become a problem if you just take in input containing a double quote value and straight use it as the value for your input (<input type="text" value="<?php echo $valueWithDoubleQuotes; ?>" />). You end up with broken html unless you use something like htmlspecialchars() in php to convert stuff like double quotes into html entities when outputting them.